# PyTables thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, pytables

I am trying to use the Python thread module together with PyTables. Can someone tell me whether PyTabes is thread-safe? I get some errors and it seems to be related to tht threading.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the PyTables FAQ here: http://www.pytables.org/moin/FAQ

It says concurrent reads are safe but that concurrent writing or even a single writer with reader threads is probably a bad idea.